# How to send eth from a specified account to a smart contract

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

If I wanted to transfer an NFT from account A to account B, and let's say that it requires an amount X to be paid. However I want an another specific account C (not on development server, but an actual Ethereum address) to pay the amount X.

Can that be done? If so, how do I do it from frontend using web3?

Comment: Well that depends whether the Smart Contract export endpoint that accept third party payment for transaction that eventually have an effect of transferring ownership for A to B, it would be easier if you publish the specific Contract address

Comment: Hi, I am creating the contract. any changes required can be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the account A (the NFT sender) needs to `approve()` the Mediator smart contract the specific token that they want to have transferred.

The Mediator smart contract will accept payment only from the Account C, and perform few other validations (such as the amount and check if it really is allowed to operate the token). Then it will perform the actual token transfer, and the ETH transfer (so that it doesn't get stuck on the Mediator contract).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface IERC721 {
    function getApproved(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address);
    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external;
}

contract Mediator {
    address accountA = address(0x123);
    address accountB = address(0x456)
    address accountC = address(0x789);
    uint256 amount = 1 ether;
    uint256 tokenId = 1;
    address collection = address(0xabc);

    function foo() external payable {
        require(msg.sender === accountC, 'Only accepting payment from Account C');
        require(msg.value === amount, 'Incorrect amount');

        IERC721 collection = IERC721(collection);
        require(collection.getApproved(tokenId) === address(this), 'This contract is not approved to operate the token');
        
        // transfer the NFT from Account A to Account B
        collection.safeTransferFrom(accountA, accountB, tokenId);
        
        // redirect the payment (from Account C to this contract) to Account A
        payable(accountA).transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

Finally, you can invoke the Mediator `foo()` function using web3. It will fail if any of the conditions is not met (such as when the sender is not Account C).

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(jsonAbi, contractAddress);
const tx = await contract.methods.foo().send({
    from: accountC,
    value: web3.utils.toWei(1, 'ether'),
});
```